# Swapping contents of columns of same datatype from different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, tablecolumn

I want to swap the column contents of same datatype from two different tables in MySQL.

Table 1

```
id value
1  aaa
2  bbb
3  ccc
```

Table 2

```
id value
1  ddd
2  eee
3  fff
```

And my new tables should be like this.

```
Table 1            Table 2

id value           id value
1  ddd             1  aaa
2  eee             2  bbb
3  fff             3  ccc
```

Is there any way to do this in MySQL?

Comment: Maybe just rename the tables.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rename-table.html

Answer (score 1):

Just do this, as commenters suggested:

```
RENAME TABLE Table_1 TO tmp_table,
             Table_2 TO Table_1,
             tmp_table TO Table_2;
```